# Animate and Plot3D not working together

Tags: graphics3d, animation, heat-equation

I made a simulator for a 2D quantum harmonic oscilator and want to display an animation of the particles moviment. For this I animated a Plot3D, but whenever the animation starts the image quality drops drasticaly. If I pause the animation and wait a few seconds the image gets better again. A link to a video showing the problem is included bellow.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1zgz0yc53vl4pj/Video_1494955312.wmv?dl=0

My code:

```
mol[n_Integer, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
     "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}(*: is for optional input*);
wx = wy = 2;
ic[x_, y_] := (wx wy/Pi/Pi)^(1/
      4) Exp[-(wx (x - 1)^2./2 + wy (y)^2./2)] ;
L = 4;
tf = 1;
eq = I D[u[t, x, y], t] + 
    1/2 (D[u[t, x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[t, x, y], {y, 2}]) == (wy^2 y^2 +
        wx^2 x^2)/2 u[t, x, y];
init = u[0., x, y] == ic[x, y];
bcs = {
   u[t, - L, y] == ic[-L, y],
   u[t, L, y] == ic[L, y],
   u[t, x, - L] == ic[x, -L],
   u[t, x, L] == ic[x, L]
   };
sys = Flatten@{eq, init, bcs};
\[Psi] = NDSolveValue[sys, u, {t, 0., tf}, {x, - L, L}, {y, - L, L}, 
  Method -> mol[53], MaxSteps -> 10^6];

Animate[Plot3D[Abs@\[Psi][t, x, y]^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, - 3, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.2}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, p}], {t, 0, tf}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False, DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

Anyone can explain why the image quality drops like this? How to fix it?

Also, possibly related, when I try to generate a .gif animation with

```
tst= Table[
   Plot3D[Abs[\[Psi][t, x, y]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, - 3, 3}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1.2}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, p}], {t, 0, tf, .1}];
```

I get no error messages, but the end result is like a ClearAll["Global`*"], all my variables are empty of content.

I am using Mathematica 10 on a win8 computer.

Comment: The [tag:bugs] tag is for bugs in built-in functions.  It is to be added only after community consensus. -- Have you tried adding `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` to your `Plot3D` code?

Comment: @MichaelE2, sorry for the mistake with the bugs tag. Would you mind telling me where do I ask to add the tag here? I do believe the behavior described in my last paragraph is a bug. If it is not, it would be nice to learn the explanation.

Comment: As asked, the answer to your question should be to use `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`.  It is by design that dynamic plots while actively being updated are drawn with poorer quality (via `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"`) unless you explicitly override the effect.  However, Kuba discovered there is a bug in `Performance` goal and has linked your question to his discovery....

Comment: As for how Qs get marked [tag:bugs], there are several ways.  (1) The user reports it to WRI and they write back that there is indeed an "issue" (or they point out the user's error). (2) You ask if this is a bug and a couple or so community members agree (usually in comments, sometimes in answers with explanation), and no one disagrees.  That's generally what has been meant by "consensus." (3) Someone from WRI comments here that it is a bug, which does not always happen since this site is independent from WRI.

Comment: The bug is said to be with Mathematica11+, I am using v10.  The bug tag was about my attempt to generate a table of figures to animate.

Comment: This [code in V10](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NAzHD.png) plus `Export["/tmp/foo.gif",tst]` gives this https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFxB2.gif -- I see no problem. Are you doing the same thing?

Comment: I restarted my computer and now the code works. Should I delete the question?

Comment: It's up to you, but you seem to have accidentally exposed a bug in another version. So it might help others who happen to have the same problem.  Strange how it worked out, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer should be set `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`. Otherwise `PerformanceGoal` options is set to global `$PerformanceGoal` which switches to `"Speed"` if the evaluation is done on a preemptive link. (default for most of gui/Dynamic etc).

See more in linked duplicate.

However, [there appears to be a bug in 11+](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146214/5478) which makes this option being ignored, fortunately Mathematica is great in workingaround bugs it introduces. So instead using the option we can `Block` the `$PerformanceGoal`:

```
Animate[
    Block[{$PerformanceGoal = "Quality"}
      ,  Plot3D[Sin[t x y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.2}]
    ]
  , {t, 0, 2}
  , AnimationRunning -> False
  , DisplayAllSteps -> True

]
```

[image]