# PerformanceGoal option ignored in V11.1

Tags: plotting, bugs, front-end, evaluation, gui-construction

**Bug introduced in 11.1 and fixed in 11.2**

> [CASE:3892079] was created
>
> [...] I have reproduced this problem with `PerformanceGoal` in version 11.1 and reported the issue to our developers [...]

---

Take this code:

```
Animate[
    Plot3D[
        Sin[t x y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}
      , PlotRange -> {0, 1.2}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
    ]
  , {t, 0, 2}
  , AnimationRunning -> False
  , DisplayAllSteps -> True
]
```

#### V10.4 correct behavior

[image]

#### 11+ regression

[image]

So it behaves like for the default `PerformanceGoal :> $PerformanceGoal`.

Can't find other explanation except [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs). Win10 here, is this the case everywhere?

Win10 V11.1.1

Comment: Same on the MacOS operating system.

Comment: Same on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: With versions 11.0.1 and 10.4.1 there is no problem on Windows 7 x64, so the regression is introduced in 11.1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### The quick fix

is to use `Block`:

```
Animate[
   Block[{$PerformanceGoal = "Quality"}
     , Plot3D[Sin[t x y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}
         , PlotRange -> {0, 1.2}
       ]
   ]
 , {t, 0, 2}
 , AnimationRunning -> False
 , DisplayAllSteps -> True
]
```

Comment: Wow, localizing the value of a variable can do the job in such a way.

Answer (score 3):

fyi, This has been fixed in 11.2. Tested it on the cloud under Linux

[image]