# Time dependent heat equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve the heat equation, namely

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} - \alpha \nabla^2 T=0$$
The problem is I have been able to solve this in Mathematica but only for steady state. I'm interested in solving it over a region (check results below).

Here's the Mathematica code for solving this

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{
   -Laplacian[T[x, y], {x, y}] == NeumannValue[0, x == 0 || y == 0 || y == 100],
   DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == 100, (x - 30)^2 + (y - 40)^2 == 20^2],
   DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == 20, x == 100]
   }, T[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

After solving it like this, I can easily acquire the heat flow vector field like this

```
Q = -Grad[sol, {x, y}];
```

And then plot it like this,

[image]

This form of solving the PDE is very natural to me so I would like to ask is it possible to solve the same problem but with the time component. Basically I would like to be able to do a `Manipulate[]` command and vary the variable `t` along some range and see how heat flows. I have tried to solve it with the same logic but Mathematica does not output correct results. Here's the code,

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{
   D[T[x, y, t], t] - Laplacian[T[x, y, t], {x, y}] == 
    NeumannValue[0, x == 0 || y == 0 || y == 100],
   DirichletCondition[
    T[x, y, t] == 100, (x - 30)^2 + (y - 40)^2 == 20^2],
   DirichletCondition[T[x, y, t] == 20, x == 100 && t == 0]
   }, T[x, y, t], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

First it outputs a warning like this one

```
NDSolveValue::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.
```

And it gives me some interpolating functions but trying any operations on them it outputs `insufficient information to interpret the result`

I have omitted some code for the sake of cleanliness, [here's the notebook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mjzp8dszmyc6z36/HeatTransferSteadyState.nb?dl=1) in case anyone needs to analyze it.

Comment: I managed to solve a very symilar equation here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146191/animate-and-plot3d-not-working-together